# user logged out frequently (Default Membership provider)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I have asp.net mvc 3 site deployed on shared hosting. My problem is that my site frequently logged out user automatically after 5 to 10 min. Although i have set the time to 200 min in web.config and application_start as shown below

```
<forms loginUrl="~/Account.mvc/index" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="200" protection="All" />



HttpCookie authCookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(userName, rememberMe);
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);   
FormsAuthenticationTicket newTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, userName, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(200), rememberMe, CurrentUser.UserID +"|"+ CurrentUser.EmployeeID);     
authCookie.Value = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newTicket);
Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
```

Comment: Where are you setting this `FormsAuthenticationTicket`? Are you using Session?

Comment: I am using cookie as shown in my edited quesiton

Comment: where are you using this code? Why are you reemiting the authentication cookie?

Comment: Actually I am saving extra info in cookie as i updated my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hopefully, this will help:

- [<machineKey decryptionKey="AutoGenerate"... being ignored by IIS. Won't invalidate previous session's cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106693/machinekey-decryptionkey-autogenerate-being-ignored-by-iis-wont-invalida)
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx

Comment: Same issue solved for me by adding the generated machineKey as well. Thanks.